# React Google Maps API Autocomplete suggestions are behind the Dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, material-ui

I'm using an `Autocomplete` component from [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) package.

[Here](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#autocomplete) is the documentation for the `Autocomplete` component.

**First case:**

As we can see in the screenshot below the `Autocomplete` gives us some suggestions under the `input` or `text field` element itself.

[image]

But when I wrap the `Autocomplete` and `text field` components inside a `Dialog` component from [Material-UI](https://v4.mui.com/), the suggestions are shown under the `Dialog` component as we can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-google-maps-yl6mg) is the code (note: please insert your Google Maps API key in the `index.js` file)

dependencies (in package.json file):

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
"@react-google-maps/api": "^2.4.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

**Second case:**

If we hit enter after inserting some characters to the `Autocomplete`, the app will crash and print an error `autocomplete.getPlaces() is not a function`

**My questions**:

1. so how can we make the suggestions from the `Autocomplete` appear directly under the `Autocomplete` itself (not under the `Dialog` component)?
2. how can we fix the error `autocomplete.getPlaces() is not a function`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dropdown element that displays behind the `Dialog` has a class name called `pac-container` (you can see it by inspecting the element). You can set the `zIndex` of it to a higher number than the `Dialog` itself to force it appearing in front of the `Dialog` background:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  dialog: {
    // the dropdown is next to the dialog root, not inside
    "& + .pac-container": {
      zIndex: theme.zIndex.modal + 1
    }
  }
}));
```

```
<Dialog className={classes.dialog}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: wow great, thank you

Comment: I am tryin it but it is not working for me. Like when inputting value in the text field the autocomplete search box is not showing at all. WHat could be the issue @NearHuscarl

Comment: Okay now it has started appearing but the thing is when I select any location from the option it doesnt set in the input fiele. It just never appears in the input. Can you help?